# How do I add a custom alert sound in macOS Sierra?

Tags: audio, macos, alert

**How do I add a custom alert sound in macOS Sierra?**  I've made some sounds I want to use in a variety of applications but when I try to add them to the */System/Library/Sounds* folder, it says *The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have the necessary permission.*  I also get the same message trying to add myself to the permissions on the Get Info window.

Comment: Okay I have **System Integrity Protection** already disable and why the file copied just with `sudo` so I've added instruction to disable/enable **System Integrity Protection**.

Comment: dragging and dropping into sound folder (/Users/< username >/Library/Sounds/), won't necessarily work. I tried to do this and it would not let me. Then I realized my sound personal sound files were 16 bit and the OS's are 24. I'm sure that's the reason. If I convert them to 24 bit it should work. Anyone?

Answer (score 7):

Copy the sound file to `~/Library/Sounds`, which is in your Home folder not `/System/Library/Sounds` in the *root* of the Macintosh HD. The sound file will then show in **System Preferences** > **Sounds** > **Sound Effects** for you to select as the *alert sound.*

Note: To expose the **Library** folder within your **Home** folder, click **Finder** > **Go** > press the <kbd>option</kbd> key and select **Library**.

**Update to address comment:**

First you need to disable **System Integrity Protection**.

1. Reboot the Mac and hold down <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> keys simultaneously after you hear the startup chime, this will boot macOS into Recovery Mode
2. When the **macOS Utilities** screen appears, click the **Utilities** menu, at the top of the screen instead, and choose **Terminal**.
3. Type the following command into **Termina**l then press <kbd>enter</kbd>:

   ```
   csrutil disable
   ```
4. You’ll see a message saying that System Integrity Protection has been disabled and the Mac needs to restart for changes to take effect
5. Reboot the Mac.

After copying the file(s) to `/System/Library/Sounds` you'll need to enable System Integrity Protection using `csrutil enable` following the steps above.

With **System Integrity Protection** disabled, then to copy the sound file(s) to `/System/Library/Sounds` you'll needed to use `sudo` with `cp` in **Terminal**.

Example:

```
cd /System/Library/Sounds
sudo cp /path/to/custom_sound.aiff .
```

Note that is a `.` at the end of the *command*, so as to copy the file into the current directory. You'll be prompted for an Administrator password when using `sudo` and when you type the password you'll not see any response as the typing of the password is hidden.  Just type the password and press <kbd>enter</kbd> for the command to execute.

Comment: I should have mentioned above that I have the sounds installed for me but I want them installed so every user will use them.  That's why I was trying to copy them to the system's sound folder.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response.  I will try it out but I have at least partially disabled SIP already so I can use TotalFinder.  I have to go back and reread their directions so I don't mess something with Total Finder which is working for me.  Thaks much though,

Comment: Security concerns notwithstanding, I would leave SIP off. You'll probably need to replace the sounds again after installing updates, and redoing the whole SIP rigamarole will get old.

Comment: If you already have Settings open, you may need to close it and re-open it.

Comment: You should not have to disable system integrity protection if you are putting the sounds in `~/Library/Sounds`.  Make sure to use an AIFF file and restart System Preferences.app

Answer (score -1):

From Apple level 9 user - an easy answer and fix for some reason not out on the net...

Open a Finder window, hold down option key and click GO....
GO>Library>Sounds (double click to open sounds- the folder will be empty if you have not added any personal sounds) then drag and drop .aiff sounds.

Comment: What exactly is an "Apple level 9 user?  That's a new one.... As for your answer, you provided nothing that wasn't already provided.

Comment: @Allan Probably an Apple Forums level 9 user (which is the highest level AFAIK)

Comment: this works on high sierra. to do without the mouse from finder: [command][shift][g] ~/Library/Sounds [enter]

Answer (score -1):

On macOS Sierra

You don't have to disable anything!
/Users/< username >/Library/Sounds/_______.aiff
It should be empty. Drag and drop your .AIFF file there then open System Preferences/Sounds, then click the Sound Effects tab, and it should be there.